# Deploying Angular website on nginx

Tags: angularjs, angular, nginx

I have a simple website built with `angular` which I want to deploy on `nginx`.

I have installed `nginx` on my pc and have modified the root and index of **nginx.conf** file as below,

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   C:/Angular-Project/angular2-trial/src;
            index  index.html;
        }
      }
```

No when I access the `localhost`, I get the index page - html content, but it doesn't resolve any Angular part. And there are no errors in the console.

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular2Trial</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**src** - Folder Structure:
[image]

Is there something else I need to do so that my angular app is functional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your structure, you haven't actually created a build.
Seems like you are using angular-cli.

Generate a build using

```
ng build --base-href .
```

dist folder is generated. Keep that in nginx.
[image]

Its content would be this.
[image]

And when u look at its index.html it should be something like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular2Liferay7</title>
  <base href=".">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Note : how pollyfills & main.bundle.js are loaded which are not in your index.html. Then Angular related stuff would be loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot...As you mentioned I did forget to build. Building it solved my problem

Comment: @Vinay: You are welcomed :) You can upvote it too :p